# Confidence interval for a sum of means from mixed model

Tags: mixed-model

I have a hypothetical dataset in which N patients are treated with intervention (int) or control (ctrl). Outcome is measured at baseline, 3, 6, 12 and 24 months.

I fit following model using lmer: `final<-lmer(prom ~ group*time + (1|id), data=data)`

My output for fixed effects is:

```
## Fixed effects:
##                    Estimate Std. Error t value
## (Intercept)         41.3333     1.1504  35.931
## groupint            -0.3333     1.6269  -0.205
## time3mos            38.1667     1.5485  24.648
## time6mos            39.5000     1.5485  25.509
## time12mos           49.3333     1.5485  31.859
## time24mos           50.5000     1.5485  32.613
## groupint:time3mos  -17.0000     2.1899  -7.763
## groupint:time6mos   -9.6667     2.1899  -4.414
## groupint:time12mos  -8.3333     2.1899  -3.805
## groupint:time24mos -11.0000     2.1899  -5.023
```

Treatment effect or the absolute difference between group means at 24 months is calculated as groupint + groupint:time24mos = -0.33333 + (-11.0000) totalling -11.3333.

My question is that how can I calculater 95% confidence interval for this effect?